# Why Bootstrap doesn't change to new line?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

This is my code. I don't understand why something like this happened.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4"><h2>My Logo</h2></div>
        <div class="span8">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="span3">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Messages</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
        test
    </div>
</div>



<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. I lose hours with this stupid code and very frustrated.

PS2. I need to add more details because this forum doesn't allow too much code.

Comment: just paste what's relevant, then you won't have problem with too much code... also, be clear with your question, what do you mean by "Bootstrap doesn't change to new line?"

Comment: ...and by the way, from the looks of it, you seem like using bootstrap 2, not 3 (referring to `span3`, `span8`... etc)

Comment: Sorry webeno, It may be Bootstrap 2 because I just follow from someone website.

Comment: @user3480543: You should follow Bootstrap's documentation if you are using BS3.

Comment: Oh! I can solve this problem now. Thank you everyone. It's because of that span!!